# SQL Server maintain order index (lineup of product)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a product lineup

```
SqNumber    Product Name
-------------------------
1           Product 1
2           Product 2
3           Product 3
4           Product 4
```

Now I am selecting the product, say product 3 and move it to "produce", so, I am deleting the row from the table

```
SqNumber    Product Name
-------------------------
1           Product 1
2           Product 2
4           Product 4
```

The next, I am renumbering `SqNumber`  (VB Script)

```
SqNumber    Product Name
-------------------------
1           Product 1
2           Product 2
3           Product 4
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make SQL keep the line numbers, not scripting in VB or C#.

Comment: You could use ROW_NUMBER when your query the table and it will always produce sequential numbers based on the rows found at run time.

Comment: `row_number() over ( order by SqNumber) as RowID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from selecting the row_number at query time (as others have suggested in comments), you could write a trigger that updates the `SqNumber` column every time a row is inserted or deleted.

By the way, I assume you **don't** use the `SqNumber` column as a primary key that is referenced by other tables, because if you did, then re-factoring it like this would be a terrible idea.